# apply() optimize() on a data frame or matrix?

Tags: r, optimization, vectorization

I have a dataframe, and a cost function that I want to optimize given each row in the data frame.

simplified example:

```
funct <- function(x,row,y)
{
  r <- row**2 - (x*y)**3
  return(sum(r))

}
apply(dataFr,1,optimize,f=funct,interval=c(0,250),y=4)
```

funct is the cost function, x is the variable I want to optimize over, and row is an argument that represents a row in a data frame dataFr

When I run the above code I get an error

```
Error in f(arg, ...) : unused argument (c(4, 8, 23))
```

What I want to get is a list of x's that optimze the cost, given each row in dataFr

dataFr can be

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  4  8 23
2  2  4 12
3  3  5 65
```

Comment: I guess the error is because of the row argument not being assigned when calling optimize(funct,..) on that row, but I dont know how to capture the row, is there a special variable in R that contains the row currently being worked on using apply?

Comment: From your example `data.frame`, what would be the expected output? As far as I can tell, if you optimize your function over `[0,250]`, the minimum will always be at `x=250`, regardless of the value of `row`.

Comment: There is no expectations from the example data.frame, the cost function I am going to use later is different, I just provided another function to make the question simlpler. What I am asking for is, how can I use apply and optimize together as described above.

Comment: The function as it is seems to cause problems as it doesn't return a single value, but is `apply(dataFr,1,function(i) optimize(funct, interval=c(0,250), row=i, y=4) )` workable?

Comment: oh, you are right, I just changed the funciton. and no, the line doesnt work, that is where the error hapens

Comment: Does `sapply(1:nrow(dataFr), function(i) optimize(funct, interval=c(0,250), row=i, y=4))` do what you want?

Comment: yes it does, so that's how I capture the row by using an anonymous function. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work:

```
apply(dataFr,1,function(r) optimize(f=funct,interval=c(0,250),row=r,y=4))
```

The problem was, as I mentioned in the comments with the row not being used and assigned to the paramter row of the function funct

By using an anonmous function, naming the current row and assigning it to the row parameter of the function it works

Comment: Those two lines are not equivalent though. The `sapply` one is passing each of the values `1:nrow` as the `row=` argument in turn while the `apply` one is passing `c(4,8,23)` etc...

Comment: you are right, after doing the calculation manually i noticed it is not doing the right thing....apply passes the whole row correctly now